# Not able to populate Partner Account field in HTML email template

Tags: email-template, configuration

I want to populate the Partner Account field value in a HTML email Template. This field is a standard lookup field(Account) and available on Opportunity page. while updating the template I do not see the merge field for Partner Account. Please help.

Thanks.